# подсчёт количества элементов в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Как подсчитать количество элементов в двумерном массиве?есть массив $arr,в нем есть массив $string,пробую подсчитать количество его элементов count($arr['string'],COUNT_RECURSIVE) выводит 0, как подсчитать количество его элементов?

```
$arr = array(
    $number =array(
        "number1" => "one",
        "number2" => "two",
        "number3" => "three"
    ),
    $string=array(
        "string1" => "str1",
        "string2" => "str2",
        "string3" => "str3"
    ),
    $people=array(
        "name1" => "John",
        "name2" => "Mike"
    )
);
echo count($arr['string'],COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую прочитать как вообще работает массив и как его заполнять.

```
$arr = [
    'number' => [
        "number1" => "one",
        "number2" => "two",
        "number3" => "three"
    ],
    'string' => [
        "string1" => "str1",
        "string2" => "str2",
        "string3" => "str3"
    ],
    'people' => [
        "name1" => "John",
        "name2" => "Mike"
    ]
];
echo count($arr['string']); // 3
```

Comment: если я попробую распечатать свой массив,то он выведется,но при этом count($arr['string']) не сработает,в твоем варианте это работает,в чем прикол?

Comment: В том, что в первом случае присваиваются переменные, во втором используются ключи.

Comment: @pompidu312123131, Это потому, что ты неправильно задаёшь значения массива. PHP куда лояльнее к ошибками, поэтому массив он, всё же, создаст, но значения значения будут `0, 1, 2`. Если сделать `count($arr[1]);`, то будет тройка.

Comment: ,ок а что делать если массив дан именно таким?

Comment: @pompidu312123131, Сказать что массив сломан и попросить переделать. Или установить ключи самому.

Comment: @TheDoctor,так если он сломан,то почему я его могу вывести?

Comment: @pompidu312123131, Рекомендую поучится читать русский текст, ибо именно им я написал - PHP лоялен к ошибкам, некоторые исправляет сам как может. Тут он исправил ключи на числа.

Comment: Тут вообще нет ошибки, это абсолютно ваилидный код. Результатом присваивания является присвоенное значение.

Comment: @Etki, Да ладно? Я сомневаюсь что автор подобное поведение имел ввиду.

Comment: @TheDoctor, я по-прежнему не понимаю, я могу заменить ключи на цифры или же наоборот строками,и будет всё так же как я говорю,следовательно дело не в этом.

Comment: @TheDoctor > "PHP лоялен к ошибкам, некоторые исправляет сам как может"

Comment: так в чем ошибка то?

Comment: @Etki, Истинная правда, брат! Ошибка разработчика, если ты не понял про что я.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут живой [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb23db4b3506ad1b11d46295052fbbdfe6a13c58)

```
$arr = array(
    $number =array(
        "number1" => "one",
        "number2" => "two",
        "number3" => "three"
    ),
    $string=array(
        "string1" => "str1",
        "string2" => "str2",
        "string3" => "str3"
    ),
    $people=array(
        "name1" => "John",
        "name2" => "Mike"
    )
);

$c =0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr)-1; $i++) {
 $c+= count($arr[$i]);

}
echo $c;
```

Либо так :

```
echo count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE);// выдаст 11
```

Comment: Так, просто любопытно - разве в `string` 8 элементов? Или я считать разучился?

Comment: Ну лично я вижу 8 элементов one, two, three, str1, str2, str3, John и Mike

Comment: нет, мне нужно подсчитать str1, str2, str3 а их 3

Comment: Автор конкретно сказал что ему нужен элемент `string`. Там 3 элемента.

Comment: Сорри, не правильно понял вопрос автора